# Parse In Today Extension "Mach-O Linked Error"

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, mach-o, today-extension

I am using Parse in my main application "App Delegate" but I also need to use it in my Today App Extension (Widget).

So I have added all the necessary frameworks to my app extension, as well as made a bridging header for parse to my app extension, finally I made sure to add the parse framework to my extension.

My "TodayViewController.swift" in my extension recognizes Parse however when I create a PFObject in it and run my application I am encountered with multiple "Mach-O Linked Errors" from my extension which looks like this:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException", referenced from:
      ___53+[PFObject(Private) deleteAllAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke226 in Parse(PFObject.o)
      ___65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke319 in Parse(PFObject.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFileManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPin.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFQuery.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(Parse.o)

I've triple checked all my frameworks, because I know most of the time that's where these errors come from. Is there something I'm missing when one wants to use Parse in an App Extension?

Also if I don't include any PFObjects or Parse related code in my App extension "TodayViewController.swift" it works.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed a fourth time, I needed the "bolts" framework and it worked!